# Name for florid corner style on a fantasy game site

Tags: style-identification

I just want to know about this sample website: http://ragnarok.levelupgames.ph/main/

As you can see, there is something CURLY on every corner of the divs.

I know about "fleur de lis" as a design element, but how do you call this kind of design? Is it "crown like corners"? I'm searching about it, but I fail.

[image]

---

Also, is there any website that has these kind of pictures in PSD/AI formats?

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has a specific name beyond 'curly border'. You can find templates for graphics like these at any decent stock site, like http://www.istockphoto.com, http://www.shutterstock.com or http://www.fotolia.com. Try searching for 'border ornament' or similar terms.

Comment: thanks sir about your comment, yah i searched the word 'border ornament' and im satisfied about the output...thanks again anyway...